# Watson Speech To Text, Word timestamps are not in sync with Audio

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

I am using speech to text with following params -
`timestamps=true&max_alternatives=1&model=en-US_NarrowbandModel&smart_formatting=true'`,

**Headers** - `'Content-Type' => 'audio/flac', 'Transfer-Encoding' => 'chunked'`

And providing an `audio/flac` file to process, but returned  words time boundary is not in sync with audio.

For eg. **Response** is -:

> take a morning I have 2 questions please %HESITATION first how how much of the ability

**Timestamps** are like these -

```
[
                            [
                                "take",
                                1409.48,
                                1409.62
                            ],
                            [
                                "a",
                                1409.62,
                                1409.67
                            ],
                            [
                                "morning",
                                1409.67,
                                1410.03
                            ],
                            [
                                "I",
                                1410.06,
                                1410.17
                            ],
                            [
                                "have",
                                1410.17,
                                1410.38
                            ],
                            [
                                "two",
                                1410.41,
                                1410.58
                            ],
                            [
                                "questions",
                                1410.58,
                                1411.05
                            ],
                            [
                                "please",
                                1411.05,
                                1411.42
                            ],
                            [
                                "%HESITATION",
                                1411.42,
                                1411.65
                            ],
                            [
                                "first",
                                1411.65,
                                1412.17
                            ],
                            [
                                "how",
                                1412.33,
                                1412.62
                            ],
                            [
                                "how",
                                1412.65,
                                1412.77
                            ],
                            [
                                "much",
                                1412.77,
                                1413
                            ],
                            [
                                "of",
                                1413,
                                1413.1
                            ],
                            [
                                "the",
                                1413.1,
                                1413.37
                            ],
                            [
                                "ability",
                                1413.37,
                                1413.82
                            ]
                        ]
```

But in actual audio these words are at different times. (few seconds difference)

Any Suggestion ??